# Гиперссылка в сообщении

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Попробовал следующий код:

```
await ctx.send("`uwu`\n\nUsage = `sun.uwu <[arg1]>`\n\nNOTE: " + ["Sunrise"]("https://discord.gg/HIDDEN") + " exclusive.")
```

Однако, когда вызваю команду, то выходит TypeError. Помогите пожалуйста, желательно объяснив как добавлять гиперссылку в сообщение.

Решено: решение ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено: гиперссылки работают только в Embed'ах.

Answer (score 0):

Гиперссылки работают не только в эмбедах, они работают и в обычных сообщениях. Вы просто  неправильно указали гиперссылку.

Гиперссылка указывается без кавычек, пример:
[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Подробнее про форматирование в Discord [здесь](https://support.discord.com/hc/ru/articles/210298617-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-101-%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%96%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-)

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Только что попробовал - вывело простое сообщение без гиперссылки.

Comment: @towerty Странно, у всех остальных всё прекрасно работает. Вы как гиперссылку ввели, покажите код

Comment: await ctx.send("[Banhammer](urlHidden)")
В таком случае бот просто отправляет сообщение: [Banhammer](urlHidden).
Ссылку скрыл, однако если перейти по ней, то появится картинка великого и знаменитого банхаммера.